# #!/bin/bash -x or -v doesn't print to stdout on Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: bash, shell-script

I'm doing one of the courses on bash, which seems a bit outdated.I have a  simple script below, which should allow me to see lines as they are read or executed, but my console gives nothing back. The $1 argument passed to bartek_report.sh is missing on purpose as I wanted to see what happens when the console hangs. Using the latest Ubuntu.

```
#!/bin/bash -v    #or -x   

# creates a report for a single container

# exercise: add a variable called 'directory'
# that determines where we save our output file

directory="reports"

mkdir -p $directory
grep $1 shipments.csv > $directory/$1.csv
echo Report created in $directory under filename $1.csv
```

When I call the script under bash it just hangs like without -x or -v, why?

```
bartek@Lenovo-LAB~/Desktop/Devs/bash_learning/02/demos/after_m2$ sh bartek_report.sh
[blinking cursor]
```

Comment: would appreciate vote for close if the question is not good, or perhaps a comment of what is the feedback to consider going forward. as I learn I can only ask you to be supportive.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're not calling your script with `bash`, as you've explicitly named `sh` as the shell with which to run the script.

The top line `#!` is only considered when you make the script executable and treat it like any other program in the system

```
chmod a+x myscript    # Make executable
./myscript            # Run it
```

As has been mentioned in [a comment](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/631778/bin-bash-x-or-v-doesnt-print-to-stdout-on-ubuntu-20-04/631781#comment1182395_631781) below this answer, you should also note that neither `-x` nor `-v` write to *stdout*. Both are debugging tools and write their messages to *stderr* so as not to interrupt the flow of any valid normal output. (So `./script >file` will leave the debugging messages written to your terminal, with the normal expected output being written to `file`.)

Comment: @steeldriver the OP already told you that. What should also be mentioned is that `-x` and `-v` write to *stderr*, not to *stdout*.

Comment: $1 is empty on purpose

Comment: @UncleBilly answer amended to include your suggestion, thank you